# building installed software

Tags: compiling

Probably a small question but if you already installed some software, like using apt and then download the source and build it then installed it using

```
 sudo make install
```

will it make confilcts with te installed package or is the original package then deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files installed by the `Makefile` will overwrite existing files, if they're in the same place. Many `Makefile`s install in the `/usr/local` tree by default. Compare `dpkg -L packagename` with `sudo make -n install`.

Comment: And use `checkinstall` instead of `make install`.